# Editing tags in a First Posts review or while asking a question showing scroll bars

Tags: bug, editing, design

When editing in a First Posts review if we edit tags in the review page, it shows scroll bars because of tags suggestion. See the below image for more clarity:

> [image]

This happened on a First Posts review on Sports.SE. I couldn't reproduce on Close Votes, Suggested Edits, Low Quality review pages.

Another example:

> [image]

---

Edit 2:

Same thing happens while asking a question too.

> [image]

Google Chrome (Version 29.0.1547.66 m), Windows XP

Comment: Doesn't happen on Stack Overflow. May be beta sites only.

Comment: @Oded - Yeah, someone tested and reported it on [Meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196126/editing-tags-in-a-first-posts-review-showing-scroll-bars?noredirect=1). So it is migrated here.

Comment: @Oded - This also happens while asking  a question. You can test it [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). :)